# How to save the GridSplitter position in ViewModel

Tags: wpf, grid, gridsplitter

I want to save the GridSplitter position in the ViewModel so that when the user returns to the DataTemplate, the Grid column settings are preserved. Binding to the GridLength property doesn't help, as it records the value in pixels, and I need the Splitter not to be able to move beyond the window boundaries, and also to preserve column proportions when the window is resized.

If someone can help write the corresponding converter, I would be very grateful, as I couldn't manage it. I hope my issue is clear.I am ready to answer questions in the comments.

```
            <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Background="Purple" x:Name="Grid" >
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="100"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="5"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Border Grid.Column="0"  Background="Red"/>
            <Border Background="Green" Grid.Column="2" />
            <GridSplitter Width="5" Background="Black" Grid.Column="1" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" ResizeBehavior="PreviousAndNext"/>
        </Grid>
```

For example, I set a fixed value for the first column [In that case, if you move the splitter to the right, it can go beyond the window boundaries](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iRm2R.png)
I also tried binding MaxWidth to the maximum values of objects inside the Grid, but it didn't help.

Comment: Such view details do not belong into the view model. You can store it in the parent control or use an attached property/behavior to manage/persist the state. For example, you could create a dedicated dependency property in your MainWindow or hosting control and bind to it. It makes sense to create a custom control to encapsulate the logic. For example, a `RestorableGrid` control.

Comment: Essentially such a control must manage the column widths (in your case column 0 and 2) of the Grid (store/restore) e.g. by handling the Loaded/Unloaded events.

Comment: Your actual concern seems to be how to prevent the GridSplitter from going out of parent Grid. If it is the case, why don't you adjust the GridLength of the leftmost ColumnDefinition depending on the ActualWidth of parent Grid when you restore the GridLength or when the Grid is resized?